# Need guidance in CSS materialize in navbar

Tags: html, css, forms, materialize

I'm trying to learn materialize CSS framework and I'm facing a little problem. It appears messy when I add a search input or when I add a grid system. I don't know why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 l12">
          <div class="nav-wrapper navbar-fixed">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="brand-logo left col s12 l4">
                    <a href="#">opplance</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <form class="col s6 l4 " method="GET">
                  <input type="search" name="" value="">
                  <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn"> <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <ul class="right col s6 l4">
                  <li> <button type="button" name="button" class="btn"><a href="#"class="right-align">Register</a></button> </li>
                  <li><button type="button" name="button" class="btn"><a href="#"class="right-align">Login</a></button></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just trying to be helpful here, but with all of the code sharing sites available now a days, there should be no reason why you aren't posting a link to a site like codesandbox, codepen.io etc. I would do that now, because other people may downvote your question.

Comment: thanks man @DanZuzevich

Comment: @DanZuzevich they should just use the Stack Snippet feature. Offsite links are generally frowned upon.

Comment: @zacknamane I added a code snippet for you.

Comment: The stack snippet feature is awful. Can't even update the code to try things out yourself.

Comment: @disinfor thank you this is exactly how it shows to me  :(

Comment: @DanZuzevich You can copy it to an answer and try there, or you can move the code to a fiddle/codepen and try it out. Only offsite links are bad, since they can expire or become invalid, which helps nobody in the future.